# Is there a Platypus-like extension for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

From [Platypus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/platypus/) Firefox Add-on page:

> Platypus is a Firefox extension which lets you modify a Web page from your browser -- "What You See Is What You Get" -- and then save those changes as a Greasemonkey script so that they'll be repeated the next time you visit the page.

This is very practical, for instance, if you want to fix rendering errors in a site you use but have no control over (like most IE-only sites).

Is there a similar extension for for Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look, but I couldn't find any. However, Google Chrome comes with developer tools (It's not really a WYSIWYG editor, more like a html/css/javascript editor.) that could do what you need them to do. Press `F12` to access them.

Comment: Can I make the changes persistent?

Comment: No, You can't make them save, unless there is a extension for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
javascript: document.body.contentEditable ='true';document.designmode ='on'; void 0
```

Copy/paste that into your browser's URL bar, but you can save as a bookmark, too.

To save, just Ctrl+Shift+I and copy the source code. That is the only real way to save the code.

Comment: Cool, this is handy.